# Why we could not catch Stopiteration exception in a generator definite function?

Tags: python, coroutine

```
def simple_generator():
    print("-> start ..")
    try:
        x = yield
        print("-> receive {} ..".format(x))
    except StopIteration:
        print("simple_generator exit..")
```

I know that each call of `next` on the generator object runs the code until the next yield statement, and returns the yielded value. If there is no more to get, `StopIteration` is raised.

So I wanted to catch the `StopIteration` in function `simple_generator` as the code above. Then I tried:

```
>>>
>>> sg3 = simple_generator()
>>> sg3.send(None)
-> start ..
>>> sg3.send("hello generator!")
-> receive hello generator! ..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

It did throw `StopIteration` while the `try ...excep` dit not catch it at all, I could not understand what's underlying reason, could anyone explain that? Thanks in advance.

Of course, I also knew that if I dealed with the `StopIteration` exception outside function `simple_generator`, it did work as what I expected, for example.

```
>>> try:
...     sg4 = simple_generator()
...     while True:
...         next(sg4)
... except StopIteration:
...     print("sg4 exit ..")
...
-> start ..
-> receive None ..
sg4 exit ..
>>>
```

So my question is **Why we could not catch Stopiteration exception in a generator definite function?**

Comment: I think, generator return iteration, so, StopIteration exception occurs while iteration operation. So, that exception can occurs outside generator function.

Comment: no exception occurs in the `try` block of your first example. the `try` block finishes nicely (by printing `print("-> receive {} ..".format(x))`). but then the generator is exhausted..

Comment: It's because a `StopIteration` isn't occurring in `simple_generator()`, it occurs as a result of the function returning `None` when it finishes.